# ¿Cómo dejar en línea un socket? Java, consola. Cliente servidor

Tags: java, socket, consola

Bueno, estoy haciendo un chat tipo cliente-servidor. Todo funciona bien pero no me deja enviar más mensajes. Creo que se debe a que se cierra la conexión con el socket, pero entonces.. ¿Cómo se deja en línea? o por lo menos, ¿cómo enviar más mensajes? Les agradeceré su ayuda :c

Cliente:

```
package pracsocket1;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;


public class Cliente {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Cliente();

}
static final String HOST = "localhost";
static final int PUERTO = 5000;


public Cliente() {

    try {

        Socket skCliente = new Socket(HOST, PUERTO);
        InputStream aux = skCliente.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream flujo = new DataInputStream(aux);
        System.out.println(flujo.readUTF());
        Scanner Gato = new Scanner(System.in);
        InetAddress receptor = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        DatagramSocket socketEmisor = new DatagramSocket();
        while(true){
           String mensaje=" ";
        System.out.println("Escribe tu mensaje" + mensaje);

        byte[] bufferEmisor = Gato.nextLine().getBytes();
        DatagramPacket datagramaEmisor = new DatagramPacket(bufferEmisor, bufferEmisor.length, receptor, 5000);
        socketEmisor.send(datagramaEmisor);

          skCliente.close();


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " Limite de Peticiones en el 
    Servidor");
    }
}

  }
```

Servidor:

```
package pracsocket1;

 import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

     public class Servidor {

static final int PUERTO = 5000;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Servidor();
}

/*consultor */
public Servidor() {
    try{
    ServerSocket skServidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO);
    System.out.println("Escucho en el puerto " + PUERTO);
    int numCli = 0;
    String nom =" "; 

    while (numCli<10) {
        numCli++;/* cuantos clientes se unen AL servidor*/
        Socket skCliente = skServidor.accept();
        System.out.println("Sirvo al cliente " + numCli);

        OutputStream aux = skCliente.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream flujo = new DataOutputStream(aux);
        flujo.writeUTF("Hola Cliente " + numCli);

        DatagramSocket socketReceptor=new DatagramSocket(5000);
        int tamanioBuffer=1000; 
        byte[] bufferReceptor=new byte[tamanioBuffer];
        DatagramPacket datagramaReceptor=new DatagramPacket(bufferReceptor, bufferReceptor.length);
        socketReceptor.receive(datagramaReceptor);
        int tamanioMensajeRecibido=datagramaReceptor.getLength();
        String mensajeRecibido=new String(datagramaReceptor.getData(), 0, tamanioMensajeRecibido);
        System.out.println("Mensaje de : " + mensajeRecibido);
        System.out.println("En la dirrección:" + datagramaReceptor.getAddress());
        System.out.println("En el puerto:" + datagramaReceptor.getPort());
        socketReceptor.close();


        skCliente.close();
    }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

      }
```

[image: Aquí escribo los mensajes]

[image: Aquí sólo recibió 1, ya no desplegó los demás]

[image: Hice unos hilos en mi clase de POO, y como que se los puse en la de cliente servidor]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Aquí se supone que le puse los hilos]

[image: Los mensajes]

[image: Aquí el servidor sólo recibió 1 mensaje]

Comment: La conexión no se cierra, `Servidor` se quedaría tildado en la linea `Socket skCliente = skServidor.accept();` aguardando mas peticiones. Para múltiples conexiones necesitas un `Thread` tanto para `Servidor` como para `Cliente` porque la comunicación también dependerá en gran parte de un bucle permanente para enviar y/o recibir los streams (mensajes). La solución es trabajar con hilos totalmente independientes.

Comment: @Johnny ya lo intenté y nada.

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado y qué mensaje de error o funcionamiento anómalo tienes y te ayudamos a corregirlo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Listo

Comment: ¿Pudiste comprobar si mi respuesta solucionó tu duda?

Answer (score 2):

He eliminado completamente todo el código que tienes que usa datagramas UDP en vez de la conexión establecida por TCP para simplificar el código.

## Servidor

El código tiene comentarios que explican el funcionamiento de cada sección. Tras él explicaré lo más importante a tener en cuenta.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Servidor
{
    static final int PUERTO = 5000;

    public class HiloDeCliente implements Runnable
    {
        /* Guardamos el socket del cliente y el número de cliente */
        Socket skCliente;
        int numCli;

        /* Constructor al que pasamos el socket del cliente */
        public HiloDeCliente(Socket skEnviado, int num)
        {
            skCliente = skEnviado;
            numCli = num;
            /* Mostramos información del cliente */
            System.out.println("Sirvo al cliente: " + num);
            System.out.println("En la dirección: " + skEnviado.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            System.out.println("En el puerto: " + skEnviado.getPort());
        }

        /* Código que atenderá al cliente hasta que cierre la conexión */
        public void run() {
            try {
                /* Mensajes recibidos */
                String mensaje;
                /* Obtenemos un DataOutputStream del socket y escribimos en él un saludo */
                DataOutputStream flujoSalida = new DataOutputStream(skCliente.getOutputStream());
                flujoSalida.writeUTF("Hola Cliente " + numCli);

                /* Obtenemos un DataInputStream para leer lo que recibamos del cliente y mostrarlo en pantalla */
                DataInputStream flujoEntrada = new DataInputStream(skCliente.getInputStream());
                while (true) {
                    /* Obtenemos el mensaje en UTF8 */
                    mensaje = flujoEntrada.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Mensaje [" + numCli + "]: " + mensaje);
                    /* Hacemos eco, sólo por depurar */
                    flujoSalida.writeUTF("Recibido mensaje: " + mensaje);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            /* Cerramos el socket */
            try {
                skCliente.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Servidor();
    }

    public Servidor() {
        try {
            ServerSocket skServidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO);
            System.out.println("Escucho en el puerto " + PUERTO);
            int numCli = 0;
            String nom = " ";

            /* No nos andamos con tonterías, aceptamos conexiones hasta finalizar la ejecución */
            while (true) {
                /* Quedamos bloqueados en este punto hasta que llegue una nueva conexión */
                Socket socket = skServidor.accept();
                /* Pasamos la información a un nuevo hilo para que atienda al cliente */
                (new Thread(new HiloDeCliente(socket, ++numCli))).start();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Lo más importante es el bucle principal del programa:

```
while (true) {
    /* Quedamos bloqueados en este punto hasta que llegue una nueva conexión */
    Socket socket = skServidor.accept();
    /* Pasamos la información a un nuevo hilo para que atienda al cliente */
    (new Thread(new HiloDeCliente(socket, ++numCli))).start();
}
```

Como puedes ver es un bucle infinito (no está limitado a un número de clientes fijo) y en él simplemente esperamos la llegada de un nuevo cliente para aceptar la conexión e inmediatamente después creamos un nuevo hilo al que pasamos como parámetro el socket del cliente y el número de cliente.

El hilo que atenderá a los clientes se define como [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) que debe implementar el método `run()`, [ejecutado en segundo plano al llamar a [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

El hilo que atiende al cliente a su vez es sencillo. Envía un mensaje de bienvenida y se queda en un bucle infinito esperando recibir mensajes:

```
/* Mensajes recibidos */
String mensaje;
/* Obtenemos un DataOutputStream del socket y escribimos en él un saludo */
DataOutputStream flujoSalida = new DataOutputStream(skCliente.getOutputStream());
flujoSalida.writeUTF("Hola Cliente " + numCli);

/* Obtenemos un DataInputStream para leer lo que recibamos del cliente y mostrarlo en pantalla */
DataInputStream flujoEntrada = new DataInputStream(skCliente.getInputStream());
while (true) {
    /* Obtenemos el mensaje en UTF8 */
    mensaje = flujoEntrada.readUTF();
    System.out.println("Mensaje [" + numCli + "]: " + mensaje);
    /* Hacemos eco, sólo por depurar */
    flujoSalida.writeUTF("Recibido mensaje: " + mensaje);
}
```

Como puedes ver obtengo las corrientes de datos de entrada y salida para poder trabajar con ellas.

En tu código mostrabas información de la dirección IP y puerto remoto, cosa que puede cambiar de datagrama en datagrama en UDP, pero es fijo durante toda la conexión en TCP, por lo que sólo lo muestro una vez durante la ejecución del constructor haciendo uso de los métodos que nos facilita [`Socket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html):

```
System.out.println("En la dirección: " + skEnviado.getRemoteSocketAddress());
System.out.println("En el puerto: " + skEnviado.getPort());
```

## Cliente síncrono

Un cliente sencillo que reciba el mensaje de bienvenida y permita enviar todos los mensajes que desees podría implementarse de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Cliente {
    static final String HOST = "localhost";
    static final int PUERTO = 5000;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Cliente();
    }

    public Cliente() {
        Socket skCliente = null;
        try {
            skCliente = new Socket(HOST, PUERTO);
            DataInputStream flujo = new DataInputStream(skCliente.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(flujo.readUTF());
            DataOutputStream flujoSalida = new DataOutputStream(skCliente.getOutputStream());
            while(true){
                System.out.println("Escribe tu mensaje");
                /* Enviamos el mensaje tecleado por consola */
                flujoSalida.writeUTF(System.console().readLine());
                /* Recibimos el eco del servidor */
                System.out.println("Eco: " + flujo.readUTF());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " Limite de Peticiones en el Servidor");
        }
        try {
            if (skCliente != null) {
                skCliente.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " Limite de Peticiones en el Servidor");
        }
    }
}
```

Tiene una limitación muy importante y es que podríamos bloquear la ejecución del programa si el eco no se produce desde el servidor.

Para solucionarlo habría que usar un hilo que se encargara de mostrar los datos recibidos en segundo plano sin bloquear el hilo principal.

## Cliente asíncrono

En esta versión del cliente se usa un hilo separado para obtener los mensajes recibidos del servidor y mostrarlos sin bloquear el programa principal.

Hay que recordar que el mensaje de bienvenida siempre bloquea el código (en este código, podría cambiarse fácilmente):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cliente {
    static final String HOST = "localhost";
    static final int PUERTO = 5000;

    public class HiloDeServidor implements Runnable
    {
        /* Guardamos el socket del servidor */
        DataInputStream flujoEntrada;

        /* Constructor al que pasamos el socket del servidor */
        public HiloDeServidor(DataInputStream flujo)
        {
            flujoEntrada = flujo;
        }

        /* Código que atenderá los mensajes del servidor de forma asíncrona */
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    /* Obtenemos el mensaje en UTF8 y lo mostramos */
                    System.out.println("Mensaje: " + flujoEntrada.readUTF());
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Cliente();
    }

    public Cliente() {
        Socket skCliente = null;
        try {
            skCliente = new Socket(HOST, PUERTO);
            DataInputStream flujo = new DataInputStream(skCliente.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(flujo.readUTF());
            /* A partir de aquí delegamos la lectura de mensajes a un segundo plano */
            (new Thread(new HiloDeServidor(flujo))).start();
            DataOutputStream flujoSalida = new DataOutputStream(skCliente.getOutputStream());
            while(true){
                System.out.println("Escribe tu mensaje");
                flujoSalida.writeUTF(System.console().readLine());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " Limite de Peticiones en el Servidor");
        }
        try {
            if (skCliente != null) {
                skCliente.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " Limite de Peticiones en el Servidor");
        }
    }
}
```

Como puede verse el código del hilo es extremadamente sencillo:

```
while (true) {
    /* Obtenemos el mensaje en UTF8 y lo mostramos */
    System.out.println("Mensaje: " + flujoEntrada.readUTF());
}
```

Simplemente queda a la espera de recibir un nuevo mensaje para mostrarlo por pantalla inmediatamente después.